# What's the best way to deep copy a hash of hashes in Perl?

Tags: perl, deep-copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to make a deep copy of a data structure in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388187/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-data-structure-in-perl)

Before I start coding this myself and reinventing the wheel, how do you copy a hash of hashes without duplicating the hashrefs?

I'm reading a hash of hash of hashes via [Config::General](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Config::General). i.e., the data structure is:

```
my %config = ( group => { item1 => { foo => 'value',
                                     bar => 'value',
                                   },
                          item2 => { foo => 'value',
                                     bar => 'value',
                                   },
                          item3 => { foo => 'value',
                                     bar => 'value',
                                   },
                        },
             );
```

I then pull my group from the config by dereferencing it and change the contents at runtime prior to rewriting the config file:

```
my %group = %{$config{'group'}};
```

The problem is that I need to check to see if changes were made and make associated changes to the system's file structure. I can't do this by checking:

```
if ($group{'item1'}{'foo'} ne $config{'group'}{'item1'}{'foo'}) {
    ### Stuff!
}
```

as `$group{'item1'}` and `$config{'group'}{'item1'}` are both the exact same hashref.

Now while it should be trivial to simply re-parse the config file, and compare the parsed copy from the disk against the edited version just before saving to disk, I'm sure there's a way to to a nested dereference of a complex data structure, copying the contents of the hash refs and not simply copying the references themselves. A cursory examination on CPAN doesn't turn anything up. What am I missing?

**Benchmark**

Got my answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Benchmark qw(:all) ;
use Storable qw(dclone);
use Clone qw(clone);

my %config = ( group => { item1 => { foo => 'value',
                                     bar => 'value',
                                   },
                          item2 => { foo => 'value',
                                     bar => 'value',
                                   },
                          item3 => { foo => 'value',
                                     bar => 'value',
                                   },
                        },
             );

my $ref = $config{'group'};

timethese(100000, {
  'Clone' => sub { my %group = %{ clone $ref }},
  'Storable' => sub {  my %group = %{ dclone $ref }},
});
```

results in:

```
Benchmark: timing 100000 iterations of Clone, Storable...
   Clone:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.26 usr +  0.01 sys =  2.27 CPU) @ 44052.86/s (n=100000)
Storable:  5 wallclock secs ( 4.71 usr +  0.02 sys =  4.73 CPU) @ 21141.65/s (n=100000)
```

Comment: If, as you say, you got your answer, you should check the post that answered your question as the correct answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
use Storable qw(dclone);
$group2 = dclone(\%group);
```

Answer (score 30):

From the Storable::dclone documentation I found [Clone](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Clone):

```
my $copy = clone (\@array);

# or

my %copy = %{ clone (\%hash) };
```

Don't need flexibility, and claims to be faster than [Storable::dclone](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html#MEMORY-STORE).

Comment: Benchmark shows this is about twice as fast as dclone

Comment: looks like this doesnt clone threads::shared data strucutre? Can't locate object method "FETCH" via package "threads::shared::tie"

Answer (score 7):

**Deep data structure 101:**

- Use [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable)'s `dclone` to make a deep copy of a structure, and `freeze` and `thaw` to serialize/deserialize them for storage (say in a database, or an http cookie (but you should encrypt anything you send to the user to make it harder to tamper with).
- Use [Data::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Compare) (or [Test::Deep](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Test::Deep) or [Test::Differences](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Differences) inside a unit test) to compare two deep data structures.
- Use [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper) or [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dump) in debugging to see what your objects look like. But don't use that as a licence to tamper with another object's internals; use the API. :)

Comment: Data::Compare's new to me as well, I've just been unwinding my hashes to check them out. I'll be sure to try it some time to compare really complicated stuff; thanks

Comment: Test::Deep, and Test::Differences are falling out of favor because of the ubiquitous Test::More's new is_deeply functionality - check it out. Dirt simple to use, and you get a pretty error.

Answer (score -3):

Could always store the hash via Storable or Data::Dumper, and reassigned the stored value into a new hash.  This should get a full copy without maintaining the referenced links.

```
use Storable;
my $serialized = freeze \%config;
my %newconfig = %{ thaw($serialized) };
```

Comment: There is special function `dclone` for this case