# In Perl, how can I make a deep copy of an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to make a deep copy of a data structure in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388187/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-data-structure-in-perl)

In my code i do:

```
@data_new=@data;
```

and then I change `@data`.

The  problem is that `@data_new` always changes as well.
It's like `@data_new` is just a reference to what's in `@data`.

How do i make a copy of an array which is not a reference but a new copy of all the values?

`@data` is a two dimensional array, by the way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The code you have **will** copy the contents of the list to a new list.  However, if you are storing references in the list (and you have to in order to create a two-dimensional array in Perl), the *references* are copied, not the objects the references point to.  So when you manipulate one of these referenced objects through one list, it appears as though the other list is changing, when in fact both lists just contain identical references.

You will have to make a "deep copy" of the list if you want to duplicate all referenced objects too.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388187/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-data-structure-in-perl) for some ways to accomplish this.

Given your case of a two-dimensional array, this should work:

```
@data_new = map { [@$_] } @data;
```

Comment: This isn't so much a deep copy as a "slightly less shallow" copy. :)

Comment: @hobbs: I never claimed it was a deep copy.  Read the sentence immediately preceding the code.

Comment: Just adding a little clarity...

Comment: To add a bit more clarity, this answer is the two-dimensional list deep copy (2-level shallow copy). By that analogy the 1-level shallow copy is simply `@data_new = @data` and we might think of array refs as zero-level shallow.

Answer (score 29):

See [perlfaq4's "How do I print out or copy a recursive data structure"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-print-out-or-copy-a-recursive-data-structure%3f).  That is, use the `dclone` method from `Storable`.

```
use Storable qw(dclone);
@data_new = @{ dclone(\@data) }
```

Comment: +1 for going to the perlfaq well.