# Why does my value change when I am not resetting it?

Tags: perl, reference

I have the following example exhibiting the problem I'm struggling to resolve.
In the toy example, I have an array `@actors` with two levels.
I also have an array of hashes `@people` which I am using to 'look up' properties of the people in `@actors`.

The output of the program should be:

```
blue, blue     cat, cat
red, red     dog, dog
blue, blue     cat, cat
red, red     dog, dog
```

but instead I'm getting:

```
blue, cat     cat, cat
red, dog     dog, dog
blue, cat     cat, cat
red, dog     dog, dog
```

That is, it seems that in setting `$favanim[$i][$j]` I seem to be also overwriting the value of `$favcols[$i][$j]`.
I suspect that for some reason the fact that `@actors` is a 2-dimensional array means that assignments via `=` are as references rather than as values, though I don't know why or how to stop it.
Please help!

The toy program is here: (I apologise if it can be simplified whilst still exhibiting the problem - it has taken me most of the afternoon to strip it down to this)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my @people = ();
$people[0]{'alternative full names for regexp'} = 'matthew smith|matt smith';
$people[1]{'alternative full names for regexp'} = 'david tennant|dave tennant';
$people[0]{'fav colour'} = 'red';
$people[1]{'fav colour'} = 'blue';
$people[0]{'fav animal'} = 'dog';
$people[1]{'fav animal'} = 'cat';

my @actors = ();
$actors[0][0] = 'David Tennant';
$actors[0][1] = 'Matt Smith';
$actors[1][0] = 'David Tennant';
$actors[1][1] = 'Matt Smith';
my @favcols = @actors;
my @favanim = @actors;

for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
  for ($j=0; $j<2; $j++) {
    my @matching_people = grep{$actors[$i][$j] =~ m/^$_->{'alternative full names for regexp'}$/i} @people;
    $favcols[$i][$j] = $matching_people[0]{'fav colour'};
    $favanim[$i][$j] = $matching_people[0]{'fav animal'};
    print "$matching_people[0]{'fav colour'}, $favcols[$i][$j]     $matching_people[0]{'fav animal'}, $favanim[$i][$j]\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
@favcols = map { [@$_] } @actors;
@favanim = map { [@$_] } @actors;
```

Deep copy vs shallow copy.

Comment: Thanks that works!
How can I modify it to work in the case that `@actors` is a 3-dimensional array?

Comment: Actually, now I know what to search for, these questions helped!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390030/in-perl-how-can-i-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-array
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388187/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-data-structure-in-perl
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-print-out-or-copy-a-recursive-data-structure%3f

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are initialising `@favcols` and `@favanim` by copying the contents of `@people`, which contains two array references

That sets `$favcol[0]` and `$favanim[0]` to a reference to the *same* array, `[ 'David Tennant', 'Matt Smith' ]`, so when you modify `$favcols[$i][$j]` and then `$favanim[$i][$j]` you are overwriting the *same array element*

I don't see any reason to initialise your arrays at all, and if you declare them as just

```
my (@favcols, @favanim);
```

then you will find that your program does what you expect

By the way, you *must always* `use strict`, and `use warnings` is preferable to `-w` on the command line

Comment: @JackB: Why do you want to copy the `@actors` array anyway, since you're overwriting the data?

Comment: Thank you very much, for the explanation and the tip about declaring the variables without initialising them.

In my actual script (not the toy example above) I wasn't overwriting all the values. But I have found a way around this now.
So your answer was the best for me, though Raghuveer's answered the question I actually asked so I'll accept that one. (I would up arrow this but apparently I don't have enough reputation!)