# how to use perl references correctly

Tags: perl, reference

I have a very noob-ish question here regarding refs, though still confounding to me at the very least...
In the code example below, i'm trying to create a hash of arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Quotekeys = 0;

my @a1 = ( 'a1', 1, 1, 1 );
my @a2 = ( 'a2', 2, 2, 2 );

my $a1_ref = \@a1;
my $a2_ref = \@a2;

my @a = ( $a1_ref, $a2_ref );

my %h = ();

for my $i ( 1 .. 2 ) {
        $h{"$i"} = \@a;
}

say Dumper \%h;
```

The Dumper output is

```
{
          '1' => [
                   [
                     'a1',
                     1,
                     1,
                     1
                   ],
                   [
                     'a2',
                     2,
                     2,
                     2
                   ]
                 ],
          '2' => $VAR1->{'1'}
        }
```

The question here is:
why is $h{'2'} a reference to $h{'1'}? I'm trying to create a hash %h with identical key-values made of the @a array-of-arrays. I want each key-value of the hash to have it's own AoA based on @a, but i'm getting references to $h{'1'} instead. What am i doing wrong??
The Dumper output i'm trying to achive is:

```
{
          '1' => [
                   [   
                     'a1',
                     1,  
                     1,  
                     1   
                   ],  
                   [   
                     'a2',
                     2,  
                     2,  
                     2   
                   ]   
                 ],  
          '2' => [
                   [   
                     'a1',
                     1,  
                     1,  
                     1   
                   ],  
                   [   
                     'a2',
                     2,  
                     2,  
                     2   
                   ]   
                 ]   
        }
```

Any help appreciated. thanks in advance!
-dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that `$h{'2'}` is a reference to `$h{'1'}`, but that both are references to the same array, namely `@a`. What you probably want is:

```
for my $i ( 1 .. 2 ) {
    $h{"$i"} = $a[$i - 1];
}
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
$h{'1'} = $a[0];   # i.e., $a1_ref
$h{'2'} = $a[1];   # i.e., $a2_ref
```

which makes `$h{'1'}` a reference to `@a1` and `$h{'2'}` a reference to `@a2`.

Incidentally, you might find it helpful to use the notations `[ ... ]` and `{ ... }` to create references to *anonymous* arrays and hashes (respectively). Since you never use `@a1` and `@a2` except via `$a1_ref` and `$a2_ref`, you might as well create the latter directly:

```
my $a1_ref = [ 'a1', 1, 1, 1 ];   # reference to a new array (no name needed)
my $a2_ref = [ 'a2', 2, 2, 2 ];   # ditto
```

---

**Edited for updated question:** To copy an array, you can write:

```
my @orig = (1, 2, 3);
my @new = @orig;
```

or:

```
my $orig_ref = [1, 2, 3];
my $new_ref = [@$orig_ref]; # arrayref -> array -> list -> array -> arrayref
```

In your case, if I understand you correctly, you need to perform a slightly "deep" copy: you don't just want two arrays with the same elements, you want two arrays whose elements are references to distinct arrays with the same elements. There's no built-in Perl way to do that, but you can write a loop, or use the `map` function:

```
my @orig = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]);
my @new = map [@$_], @orig;
```

So:

```
for my $i ( 1 .. 2 ) {
    $h{"$i"} = [map [@$_], @a];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ruakh, but that's not exactly what i was trying to achieve. I've updated my post with more info. that's a good tip regarding the reference notations.

Answer (score 2):

This (what you are doing) will make `$h{1}` and `$h{2}` refer to the same array, `@a`:

```
    for my $i ( 1 .. 2 ) {
        $h{"$i"} = \@a;
    }
```

This will make `$h{1}` and `$h{2}` refer to two different objects, each one being *a copy of* `@a`:

```
    for my $i ( 1 .. 2 ) {
        $h{"$i"} = [ @a ];
    }
```

But the inner arrays will still be aliased. It sounds like you want a **deep copy**:

- [Perl FAQ: How do I print out or copy a recursive data structure?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-print-out-or-copy-a-recursive-data-structure%3f)
- [What's the best way to make a deep copy of a data structure in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388187/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-data-structure-in-perl)

Answer (score 2):

I think this code does what you want.

I have switched to [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDump) because I prefer its output.

The problem with taking the reference of data is that, no matter how many times you copy that reference, it still points to the same data, so a change in that data is relected everywhere the it is referred to.

To produce a second, independent copy of, say, an array, you can of course write `my @copy = @array` and work from there. But it is convenient to use `[ @array ]` which copies the contents of the array to a new anonymous array and returns a reference to it.

You want each hash value to be a reference to a two-element array, each of which is a reference to another array containing the data from `@a1` and `@a2`. This code will do that for you.

Another point is that, since hash keys are strings, it is unusual to use numeric values for them: it indicates that you should be using an array instead. But since all of this is clearly placeholder data I am not too worried about it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my @a1 = qw/ a1 1 1 1 /;
my @a2 = qw/ a2 2 2 2 /;

my %h;

for my $i ( 1, 2 ) {
  $h{$i} = [ [ @a1 ], [ @a2 ] ];
}

dd \%h;
```

**output**

```
{
  1 => [["a1", 1, 1, 1], ["a2", 2, 2, 2]],
  2 => [["a1", 1, 1, 1], ["a2", 2, 2, 2]],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above pointed me to the correct solution (and the issue). And that's the need to make a copy of the structure and then use the reference to it. The arrays and hashes i pointed out here was just placeholder for a more complicated structure.  So to make a copy of the structure i used the [Clone](http://search.cpan.org/~garu/Clone-0.34/Clone.pm) module, which does exactly a deep copy of a the structure and return a different reference to it.
Thanks all for the replies!