# Why do duplicate entries of hashes in an array reference the first entry in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Restating the question, why do duplicate entries of hashes in an array reference the first entry in Perl? Please correct my terminology if I am mistaken but, when I push identical hash references into an array with the code below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my @array;
my %hash = (foo => 'foo', bar => 'bar');

for (1..3) {
    push @array, \%hash;
}

print Dumper @array;
```

I get the following result:

```
$VAR1 = { 
          'bar'=> 'bar',
          'foo'=> 'foo'             
        };
$VAR2 = $VAR1;
$VAR3 = $VAR1;
```

I expected to see the following result:

```
$VAR1 = { 
          'bar'=> 'bar',
          'foo'=> 'foo'             
        };
$VAR2 = { 
          'bar'=> 'bar',
          'foo'=> 'foo'             
        };
$VAR3 = { 
          'bar'=> 'bar',
          'foo'=> 'foo'             
        };
```

Is this behavior because of a fundamental Perl concept or because of `Data::Dumper`?

Answer (score 6):

Basically you already said it yourself (emphasys mine).

> Please correct my terminology if I am mistaken but, when I push **identical hash references** into an array with the code below

That's because you push in a *reference* to the hash. In each iteration of the loop, it's always *the same hash*, so *each **new** reference* goes to that same hash.

If you use [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer)'s `p`, the output is as follows, which I find clearer than the [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) one.

```
[
    [0] {
        bar   "bar",
        foo   "foo"
    },
    [1] var[0],
    [2] var[0]
]
```

It's obvious it's pointing to the same thing. Now if you run this code:

```
for (@array) {
    say $_;
}
```

The output will be three times the same address.

```
HASH(0x2755150)
HASH(0x2755150)
HASH(0x2755150)
```

The whole idea of a reference is to reference the same thing. That's a very powerful tool, because that way you save memory. If your `$hash` is actually not just a tiny hash, but a large object (let's say a [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) object that can hold parsed HTML documents), passing it around would be super expensive.

But with the reference, every piece of code that gets it *shares* it. That's way more efficient.

For more information on this, you should read [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

---

If, however, you want a copy, you need construct your own hash reference instead of referencing the hash you already have. That's what [@toolic said in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066256/why-do-duplicate-entries-of-hashes-in-an-array-reference-the-first-entry-in-perl/35066283#comment57855690_35066256).

```
my %hash = (foo => 'foo', bar => 'bar');

for (1..3) {
    push @array, { %hash };
}
```

And if you have an existing reference, and you want a copy, dereference it first.

```
my $ref = { foo => 'bar' };
my $shallow_copy = { %{ $ref } };
```

If you need a deeper copy, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390699/1331451).

Comment: @t I'm not going to try to find the meta discussion about whether to use _their_ around here on my phone and instead just assume you meant to specify it. Or maybe I just didn't get the joke. ;-)

Comment: I edited to make it more clear that it's different references to the same data structure. @vlad, perlref explains it. Look for _reference count_. I think _Object Oriented Perl_ by Damian Conway also has a chapter explaining this stuff.

Comment: @vlad: I know. But I answered it anyway. This is a crowdsourcing platform, we share knowledge here ;)