# How to make a copy of a nested array in an array of array structure

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, shallow-copy

I'm trying to make a copy of a nested array, and it appears that I continue to make a reference with my attempts.

To be more specific I am trying to have an array of arrays wherein each sub array builds upon the previous array. Here is my attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my @aoa=[(1)];
my $i = 2;
foreach (@aoa){
  my $temp = $_;#copy current array into $temp
  push $temp, $i++;
  push @aoa, $temp;
  last if $_->[-1] == 5;
} 
#print contents of @aoa
foreach my $row (@aoa){
  foreach my $ele (@$row){
    print "$ele  ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

My output is:

```
1  2  3  4  5  
1  2  3  4  5  
1  2  3  4  5  
1  2  3  4  5  
1  2  3  4  5
```

And I want/expect it to be:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
```

I'm assuming my problems lies with how I am assigning $temp, please let me know if this is not the case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388187/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-data-structure-in-perl

Comment: Generally speaking, you can use Storable's `dclone`. zdim's solution is more appropriate in this case (since you just want a simple shallow copy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new array with `my`, copy the contents of the array to be built upon, then add to it.

Keeping it as close as possible to your code

```
foreach (@aoa) {
  last if $_->[-1] == 5;
  my @temp = @$_;         #copy current array into @temp
  push @temp, $i++;
  push @aoa, \@temp;
}
```

Comment: Or if you wanted to use an anonymous array, `push @aoa, [ @$_, $i++ ];`

Comment: @ikegami Thank you very much for the edit and comment, this is much better.